# Upload image from local directory to Google Cloud Storage using Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Node JS / Express and would like to download a file from url to local system, and in the next step upload it Google Cloud Storage.

This is my router with middlewares:

```
  router.post("", fileFromUrl, uploadFromUrl, scrapeController.scrapeCreateOne);
```

this is a fileFromUrl middleware that is just saving a file from url to local disk

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
try {
    console.log('Image: ', req.body.image);

    const url = req.body.image ? req.body.image : '';
    console.log(typeof url);

    if(url === '') {
        //no image url provided
        console.log('image parsing skipped');
        next()
    }
    else {
         // image url ok then 
        const pathToImage = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'images', Date.now() + '_file.jpg');
        const localPath = fs.createWriteStream(pathToImage);
        
        const saveFile = https.get(url, (response) => {
            console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
            response.pipe(localPath);
        })

        req.body.customImageUrl = pathToImage;
        req.body.customImageName = path.basename(pathToImage);
        
        next();
    }

}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

}

this is uploadFromUrl middleware that should upload the file from local path to the Google Cloud Storage

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
try {
    console.log(req.body.customImageUrl);
    console.log(req.body.customImageName);
    //storage.getBuckets().then(x => console.log(x));
    //storage.createBucket(`testbucket_${Date.now()}`); / // it does work
    storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(req.body.customImageUrl, {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
        },
    }).then(
        req.body.customData = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${req.body.customImageName}`
    ); 
    next();
}
catch (error) {
    res.send(error).json({
        message: 'Error upload middleware' + error,
    });
}
```

}

What is does right now, is just uploading almost empty file with 20kB to the Google Cloud Platform, not the full image. I feel that I'm not providing a proper file object to the uploadFromUrl middleware. On the other hand GCP API to upload a file is just asking for the path to the file which is being provided. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi @luk have you confirmed that when you are saving the file locally it has the correct size? This should confirm if it's an issue when downloading the file or when uploading it.

Comment: hi @gso_gabriel yes, first middleware (fileFromUrl) correctly saves the image in the images folder on my node server. I can view all the files and they do have a proper size

Comment: Hi @luk if it's saving, probably is related to the URL you are passing to the upload. Considering that, could you please give it a try following this tutorial [here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/node-js-upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage) and check if it helps you? It provides some examples on how to upload local files to GCS.

Comment: Thank you again. I haven't found the solution yet but I found the issue. In case I broke down the request by two, and call one request to save the file from url to local server disk, and then second request to grab this saved file and upload to GCP it is all good as expected. It must be the issue that I'm trying to upload the file to GCP that is not yet fully saved on the local server

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: @double-beep thank you for kind moderation, added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to upload image to GCP, even though the image was not yet fully saved on the server. The solution was to wait for 'finish' event in the request I made to save it locally

```
 const pathToImage = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'images', Date.now() + '_file.jpg');
        const localPath = fs.createWriteStream(pathToImage);
        const fileRelativePath = "images/" + path.basename(pathToImage);
        const request = https.get(url, (response) => {
            //console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
            response.pipe(localPath).on('finish', () => {
                console.log('image saved on the server');
                req.body.customImagePath = fileRelativePath;
                req.body.customImageName = path.basename(pathToImage);
                // now you can go and upload the image to GCP in the next moddleware
                next();
            });
        });
```